# raspberry pi stuck on "welcome to pixel" page

Tags: boot, hdmi

I am a college student working on a raspberry pi project. I recently got my raspberry pi and I was able to display the pi on a TV monitor via HDMI few days ago. However, I had to download some contents for a pi-specific screen from https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pitft-3-dot-5-touch-screen-for-raspberry-pi/detailed-install and now it only displays on this pi-specific screen; whenever I connect the pi to the TV monitor, the pi is always stuck on the "Welcome to Pixel Powered by Raspbian" page with "rc-local.service" at the bottom left corner of the screen. It would be ideal to have the raspberry pi to be functional with both the pi-specific screen and the TV monitor. Please help. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.